# Ansible: make output from a command become a key-value item/variable for the next command

Tags: variables, output, ansible, allocation

I want to use this output (from a previous command) as an array of key-values or as an inventory for the next command in the same playbook

```
stdout:
hot-01: 10.100.0.101
hot-02: 10.100.0.102
hot-03: 10.100.0.103
....
hot-32: 10.100.0.132
```

like this:

```
- shell: "echo {{ item.key }} has value {{ item.value }}"
  with_items: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```

or:

```
- add_host: name={{ item.key }} ansible_ssh_host={{ item.value }}
  with_items: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```

Desired output of the echo command:

```
hot-01 has value 10.100.0.101
```

I also tried with with_dict: "{{ output.stdout }}" but still no luck

```
"fatal: [ANSIBLE] => with_dict expects a dict"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there are no Jinja2 filters to convert strings to dictionaries.

But in your specific case, you can use the [python's `split` string function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) to separate the key from the value:

```yaml
- shell: "echo {{ item.split(': ')[0] }} has value {{ item.split(': ')[1] }}"
  with_items: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```

I know, having to use split twice is a bit sloppy.

As in this case your output is a valid YAML, you can also do the following:

```yaml
- shell: "echo {{ item.key }} has value {{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: "{{ output.stdout | from_yaml }}"
```

As a last resort, you can also create your own ansible module to create a Jinja2 filter to cover your case. There is an `split` module filter that you can use as inspiration here: https://github.com/timraasveld/ansible-string-split-filter

Comment: Just as a side question: How can i use with_dict in this case? I mean .stdout or .stdout_lines would be a key but how can i use with_dict? Your answer does what i wanted but i'm trying to find a prettyer solution :)

Comment: I added an example using `with_dict`.